# Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve footer.component.css" didn't return a string

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Tengo un problema al crear un componente footer con Angular. Muestra este error:

> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'footer.component.css?ngResource' in 'clientes-app'
>
> Error: The loader "footer.component.css" didn't return a string.

Esto no permite que pueda ver el footer, ¿cómo puedo resolverlo?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-footer',
templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent {
    public autor: any = {nombre: 'Johan', apellido: 'Ruiz'};
}
```

Comment: ¿Tienes un archivo `.css` ?